# Importing Xcode project to Unity

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, unity-game-engine

I have a project developed in Xcode and I would like to import to Unity or add it as a feature to existing Unity project. Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

You can not import Xcode project to Unity but you can create plugin in unity and you can access your Xcode code from unity.

For example in you iPhone app you have integrated Facebook and you want to access that Facebook integration in to your app then you should created plugin for that.

[Here is the reference.](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/PluginsForIOS.html)